# Labeling plot maximum peaks in GNUPlot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have some data that I'm plotting with GNUPlot. I have three different data sets for different energies. What I need to do is label the maximas on the plot. For example, I need something like (20, 4.5) for the red plot. The values do not need to be above the maximas, as they only need to be distinguishable to which is what. Is there any easy way to do this in GNUPlot? I haven't been able to find anything online.

Thanks in advanced. Below is an example plot that I'm trying to work with. It wouldn't let me post images so I'm posting the link below.

http://i.imgur.com/xA3q52I.png

Answer (score 0):

I think this example can help

http://www.gnuplot.info/demo/stats.html